# Passar $_POST via javascript e redirecionar

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho uma página que pega o tamanho da tela do usuário via Javascript e a outra que recebe os dados para exibição. Só que não consigo passar o `$_POST` para outra página, já que não redireciona.

**Width.php**

```
<script> 
var wi = screen.width;
$.post("Index-m.php", {screen: wi} );
window.location.replace("Index-m.php");
</script>`
```

**Index-m.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['screen'])){
    $resolution  = $_POST["screen"];
    if ( $resolution >= 768)
        echo "teste";
            else{
                if ( $resolution >= 480 and $resolution <= 767)
                    echo "teste 2";
                        else{
                            if ( $resolution <= 479)
                                echo "teste 3";
                            }
                }
    } else
echo 'oi';
```

OBS:Não posso passar por `$_GET` pois esta resolução será para carregar imagens ou vídeos e resolver o problema do design responsivo na versão mobile (Baixa velocidade).

Comment: "Designer Responsivo" -> "design responsivo"

Comment: não entendo porque está realizando operações server side se o layout usa design responsivo. Uma das propostas do responsive design é justamente eliminar esse custo de processamento server-side.

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio não tinha visto que $wi estava no código realmente deveria ser $resolution, mais como eu tentei de outras formas realizar o código acabei não alterando antes de enviar a pergunta.

Comment: @DanielOmine estou a realizar esta operação para verificar se á possibilidade de melhorar a velocidade da navegação móvel pois o design responsivo até facilita muito mais tem hora que o site demora a carregar no 3G, meu site é responsivo mais tenho funções que usam muito da rede então por isso do código quero ver se á alguma possibilidade de melhorar isso.

Comment: entendo.. imaginei isso.. acho que poderia fazer como antigamente onde direcionava para um subdominio.. mobile.nomedosite....  entendeu? Aliás, isso ainda é muito usado pois nem todo dispositivo mobile é compatível com html.. ainda há muitos mobiles com tecnologias defasadas como o wml.

Comment: Pensei nesta opção mais teria de recriar o conteúdo de pagians inteiras então assim facilita pois o $_GET não muda e  90% do conteúdo continua intacto só parte dele modifica por exemplo vídeos e imagens ou até mesmo classes php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está usando ajax (acredito eu), ajax é assíncrono, ou seja só funciona com "callbacks", se você redirecionar a página com `location` logo após chamar o ajax o redirecionamento irá abortar a requisição do Ajax.

Isto é jQuery? Se for o código deveria ficar assim:

```
var wi = screen.width;
$.post("Index-m.php", { screen: wi }).done(function() {
    window.location.replace("Index-m.php");
}).fail(function() {
    alert("error");
});
```

Também parece haver um problema no seu PHP, note que aqui você usa a variavel `$resolution`:

```
$resolution  = $_POST["screen"];
```

Mas aqui você usa a variavel `$wi`

```
if ( $wi>= 768)
```

Outra coisa, usar `if` e `else` sem `{` e `}` requer muita atenção com a indentação e com a quantidade de quebra de linhas, recomendo usar sempre assim (se tiver algum erro na logica me avise):

```
if(isset($_POST['screen'])) {
    $resolution  = $_POST["screen"];
    if ($resolution >= 768) {
        echo "55";
    } else if ($resolution >= 480 && $resolution <= 767) {
        include "";
    } else if ( $resolution <= 479)
        include "";
    }
} else {
    echo 'oi';   
}
```

Não entendi o uso dos `include` vazios, mas vou supor que você removeu os nomes dos arquivos só no exemplo.

Note que ao enviar uma requisição por ajax e redirecionar depois não será exibido o mesmo conteúdo (serão duas requisições diferentes), se você na verdade necessita enviar um POST no mesmo momento que redireciona (ou seja apenas uma requisição) você terá que usar `<form>` ao invés de `$.post`, segue exemplo:

```
<form id="meuForm" action="Index-m.php" method="POST">
    <input name="screen" id="screen" type="hidden">
</form>

<script>
function testCase() {
    var screenField = document.getElementById("screen");
    var meuForm = document.getElementById("meuForm");

    screenField.value = screen.width;
    meuForm.submit();
}
</script>

<button onclick="testCase()">Testar</button>
```

No exemplo usei um botão, mas se precisar "automatizar", você pode usar `onload`:

```
<form id="meuForm" action="Index-m.php" method="POST">
    <input name="screen" id="screen" type="hidden">
</form>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var screenField = document.getElementById("screen");
    var meuForm = document.getElementById("meuForm");

    screenField.value = screen.width;
    meuForm.submit();
};
</script>
```

ou `$.ready` (jQuery):

```
<form id="meuForm" action="Index-m.php" method="POST">
    <input name="screen" id="screen" type="hidden">
</form>

<script>
$.ready(function() {
    var screenField = document.getElementById("screen");
    var meuForm = document.getElementById("meuForm");

    screenField.value = screen.width;
    meuForm.submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Deu certo, sim o include vazio era só no exemplo e o $wi foi um teste que fiz e esqueci de alterar

Comment: @Eder Imaginei isso :)

Comment: Obg afinal eu sou formado em php/ html /css e não em java alias não sei muito diferencia jquery de javascript ainda estou aprendendo, então fui seguir uns tutorias e não deu muito certo sua resposta resolvel o problema

Comment: @Eder jquery é apenas uma biblioteca para javascript, ou seja jquery é javascript -- Já o java é uma coisa totalmente diferente de javascript, só os nomes que são semelhantes, na verdade java se trata de uma linguagem mantida pela Oracle, usada em máquinas virtuais para desenvolvimento diversos tipos de software, como Desktop, Android e páginas web (server-side).